# which command spring cloud data flow uses to run tasks?

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow, spring-cloud-task

Currently I am not using spring cloud dataflow, though I am creating tasks in my application and running them through command line. Currentlt I am thinking to move to spring cloud data flow via kubernetes. So my concern is first, how can I reuse my current code? and which command does data flow deployer use to run tasks ?

Answer (score 0):

This [guide](https://dataflow.spring.io/docs/batch-developer-guides/getting-started/task/) will get you started on how to setup a task on Spring Cloud Data Flow.

In Summary, this is what you need to do:

- Register your task as a `task` application type in SCDF
- Create a task definition
- Launch your task with arguments and properties

You can either use Spring Cloud Data Flow Dashboard or Shell to perform the above operations.

Comment: You need to convert your current code into Spring Cloud Task app and do the above steps. The above guide mentioned will help you on how to do that.